# How to create SQL Variable byRef (Refreshing its value) in T SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm wondering if I can create a variable in T-SQL which refreshes itself during the flow of script.

I want to create a variable which references to other 2 variables' summation.

For instance:

```
DECLARE @Number1 INT
DECLARE @Number2 INT
DECLARE @Total   INT
SET @Number1 = 5
SET @Number2 = 10

SET @Total = @Number1 + @Number2
SELECT @Total
```

This will show 15.

However, if I set in later lines of the script :

```
SET @Number1 = 15
SET @Number2 = 25

SELECT @Total
```

It will still show 15. I know that during the assignment, it got the value of @Number1 + @Number2 .

Is there any way to update/refresh @Total variable's value without doing :
`SET @Total = @Number1 + @Number2` to refresh its value?

I'm looking for, once either @Number1 or @Number2's value is changes (or both changed), @Total is also recalculated automatically.

I have looked around but couldn't find any info regarding that. Maybe it was kinda hard to make a "search term" on google for what I'm looking.

Thanks.

Comment: `set @Total = 0` before you do something else with this variable.

Comment: No variables are not going to update automagically. If you want the sum of two variables you will have get the sum of two variables. This is just like any other programming language. Variables are not by reference like that within the same method in any language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this with a variable.

2 alternatives, which probably won't help but will show you how unwieldy it will be to try to do what you're asking:

You could do it with a computed column in a table, where you would replace all three variables with columns in the table, and instead of setting and getting varibles you would insert and select from the table, or

You could do it with a UDF, where everytime you wanted to reference the value of Total, you would call fnTotal(Number1, Number2).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a trigger (or an event) on a TSQL variable. There are triggers that work somewhat like what you are asking for that pertains to columns, and or rows, in a table.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have this as a single variable. But if you really wanted this, you could use a table variable with a computed column:

```
DECLARE @V TABLE(Number1 INT, Number2 INT, Total AS Number1 + Number2);
INSERT @V (Number1, Number2) VALUES (5, 10);

SELECT Total FROM @V;  -- 15

UPDATE @V SET Number1 = 15, Number2 = 25;

SELECT Total FROM @V;  -- 40
```

This is cute, but I definitely don't recommend doing this in a production system. Using a table for this rather than separate variables is pretty inefficient -- table variables use I/O in tempdb, and while much of this is optimized and doesn't actually touch the disk, having I/O just because you don't want to add two numbers together is pretty heavy, especially if you started using this technique everywhere.

If you are not opposed to redoing the addition, you could still save on typing a bit by making use of multiple assignment:

```
DECLARE @Number1 INT, @Number2 INT, @Total INT;
SELECT @Number1 = 5, @Number2 = 10, @Total = @Number1 + @Number2;

SELECT @total   -- 15

SELECT @Number1 = 15, @Number2 = 25, @Total = @Number1 + @Number2;

SELECT @total   -- 40
```